# Showing error message while posting comment, open Review task page

Tags: discussion, support, error-message

I am getting an error message while trying to put a comment on a post. the message saying that "An error occurred during comment submission". Same thing happens while clicking closed votes from [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close). I have attached the screen shots of both.

[image: Shows while posting comment]
[image: shows while loading reviews]

Browser's console shows me that

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 418
>   (I'm a teapot)

I cannot post anything, How can i solve this? I can do all in meta but not in SO

Comment: Do you know how to use your browser's console to see what the error is? It is probably the perennial problem of JavaScript getting blocked, since this is failing in multiple places on the site.

Comment: Stack Overflow returning error 418 [suggests that a CSRF violation occurred](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185449) (or that if you send a `BREW` command, you can get a fresh pot).