# I have found an unreviewable answer it seems

Tags: bug, late-answers

While going through late-answers review queue it seems I have found one answer that cannot be reviewed.

This never happened to me before. No matter what action I try to do, the server response is `418` and FE interprets it as a generic error.

The only way to continue the review was to use `back` browser button and to let the system roll again on the next question from the queue.

I also tried visiting the review link once I finished and the error still occurs there albeit I cannot even see the answer content.

Link to the review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/33815076

Screenshot under review:
[image]

Screenshot after review:
[image]

My guess is that some kind of bug occurred, but perhaps I am wrong. Anyway I think it is a good idea to share this is happening.

Comment: Seems to have been some other error between you and that user. I can't reproduce it (works fine for me), so it may be better for someone on the SO team to check.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. The error still occurrs for me...

Comment: I can confirm that the link works and shows the review item. I can also see that LeoDog896 was able to perform the review. I guess that needs a developer to look at it if it keeps happening.

Comment: Thanks to you too. Should I summon a developer by some means? Tag or something perhaps?

Comment: meta.stackoverflow.com is behaving glitchy right now too, failing to load etc. The daily ddos or wild beavers in the server room, something like that.

Comment: Maybe [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317898/showing-error-message-while-posting-comment-open-review-task-page)?